# reading empty Rows from Excel ( *.xlsx )

Tags: c#, windows, excel, datagridview, visual-studio-2013

While I am reading from excel using this code:

```
OpenFileDialog ofd= new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Title = "Select file";
ofd.Filter = "Excel Sheet(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
ofd.FilterIndex = 1;
ofd.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (ofImport.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(ofImport.FileName);
    string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet6$]";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ofd.FileName + ";Extended Properties=" + "\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
    var ds= new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    DataTable data = dsz.Tables[0];
    datagridview1.DataSource = data
    // to get row count
    int rowCount = dg_Un_TIA.Rows.Count;
    // Get the no. of columns in the first row.
    int colCount = dg_Un_TIA.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
```

And after the code compiled i see that the `rowCount = 1048574` and `colCount = 17`, but in the file the rows filled with `data = 9000` and `columns = 14`

How to read those only and what the changes will be in the code 
because I got `out of memory Exception` ...

Comment: Does this happen with an empty file as well?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that this has something to do with the XLSX file being used. The following code, which is based on your sample with a couple of changes to which variables were being looked at, provides the expected results with a newly created Excel document:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                Title = "Select file",
                Filter = "Excel Sheet(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All Files(*.*)|*.*",
                FilterIndex = 1,
                RestoreDirectory = true
            };

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection
                {
                    ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ofd.FileName +
                                       ";Extended Properties=" + "\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\""
                };
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);

                var ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                DataTable data = ds.Tables[0];

                var message = string.Format("Row Count: {0}{1}Column Count: {2}", data.Rows.Count, Environment.NewLine, data.Rows[0].ItemArray.Count());
                MessageBox.Show(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With an empty document the above code will crash but does return a row count of 0.

Comment: i cant understand how this will remove the empty rows

Comment: He's basically telling you that the rows aren't empty. I bet you have something on the 1048574th row.

Comment: When you set up your query string: SELEcT * FROM [Sheet1$] this appears to take into account which rows have data populated and which don't. It's a little odd that you're getting the specific number 1048574 as this is almost (but not quite once the header has been excluded) the maximum number of rows in an excel document. Could you try the above code with a newly created document and see what you get?

Comment: its empty rows and come empty to the gridview

Comment: Check for spaces as well, how are you seeing this on a grid if you get an OutOfMemory exception as you mentioned?

Comment: I've implemented the above using a DataGridView and it works as expected. Could you explain what dg_Un_TIA refers to in your code sample?